# Como insertar un elemento con JS

Tags: javascript

Yo tengo mi input de ingresar operandoA y operandoB, al final de todo tengo un botón para obtener el resultado de la operación entre esos dos operandos. Ahora, yo lo que quiero es que al apretar el botón me verifique que ambos campos no estén vacíos, para ello necesito el atributo **required** lo que no se, es como implementarlo correctamente para este caso teniendo un botón, como seria?
Ya he buscado pero no logro encontrar algo claro, usan jQuery la mayoría y los que están en JS están muy mal explicados.

```
    <div class="contenedor">
        <h1>Calculadora con JS</h1>

        <form class="formularioClase" id="formCalculadoraID">

            <div class="contenedorSeleccion">
                <label class="labelClase" for="selectorID">Elije la operacion</label>
                <select id="selectorID" name="nameOperacion">
                    <option value="Suma">Suma</option>
                    <option value="Resta">Resta</option>
                    <option value="Multiplicacion">Multiplicacion</option>
                    <option value="Division">Division</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="contenedorInput">
                <label class="labelClase" for="operandoA">Operando A</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el primer operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoA"/>

                <label class="labelClase" for="operandoB">Operando B</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el segundo operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoB"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        
        <button class="botonResultado" onclick="mostrarResultado()">Resolver</button>
        <div class="resultadoObtenido" id="resultadoObtenidoID">Resultado:</div>
    </div>
```

```
let mostrarResultado = () => {
    let formulario = document.getElementById('formCalculadoraID');
    let operandoA = Number(formulario['operandoA'].value);
    let operandoB = Number(formulario['operandoB'].value);
    let operacion = formulario['selectorID'].value;
    let resultado = '';

    console.log(`Se ha gestionado la operacion: ${operacion}`);
    resultado = operaciones[operacion](operandoA, operandoB);

    document.getElementById('resultadoObtenidoID').innerHTML = `Resultado: ${resultado}`;
}
```

Comment: en los inputs debes colocar la propiedad 'required', ves que tienes propiedades como type='Number' o class='inputClass'? bueno ahi es donde debes agregar 'required' a secas

Comment: Claro, pero aun si lo pongo ahi, al hacer click en "Resolver" no me gestiona esto, yo necesito que lo haga

Comment: Tu código no es reproducible, que se supone que hace esto? `resultado = operaciones[operacion](operandoA, operandoB);` -> tienes alguna otra función que haga la operación con estos 2 parámetros? adjunta tu JS completo.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no tiene sentido, pero como no entra en la pregunta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero, a 'botonResultado' y 'resultadoObtenido' colócalos dentro del form, al botón elimínale la llamada a la funcion asociada al evento onclick y agrégale la propiedad type='submit', además de agregar 'required' a los inputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h1>Calculadora con JS</h1>
    <form class="formularioClase" id="formCalculadoraID">
      <div class="contenedorSeleccion">
        <label class="labelClase" for="selectorID">Elije la operacion</label>
        <select id="selectorID" name="nameOperacion">
          <option value="Suma">Suma</option>
          <option value="Resta">Resta</option>
          <option value="Multiplicacion">Multiplicacion</option>
          <option value="Division">Division</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="contenedorInput">
        <label class="labelClase" for="operandoA">Operando A</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el primer operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoA" required />
        <label class="labelClase" for="operandoB">Operando B</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa el segundo operando" class="inputClass" id="operandoB" required />
      </div>
      <button class="botonResultado" type="submit">Resolver</button>
      <div class="resultadoObtenido" id="resultadoObtenidoID">Resultado:</div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

El elemento que llame a la funcion sera el propio formulario, que se desencadena al hacer submit sobre el boton del formulario que tenga el type='submit' como propiedad, lo hacemos con JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("formCalculadoraID").onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  mostrarResultado();
};

let mostrarResultado = () => {
  let formulario = document.getElementById("formCalculadoraID");
  let operandoA = Number(formulario["operandoA"].value);
  console.log(operandoA);
  let operandoB = Number(formulario["operandoB"].value);
  let operacion = formulario["selectorID"].value;
  let resultado = "";
  console.log(`Se ha gestionado la operacion: ${operacion}`);
  resultado = operaciones[operacion](operandoA, operandoB);
  document.getElementById(
    "resultadoObtenidoID"
  ).innerHTML = `Resultado: ${resultado}`;
};
```

Comment: Eso me parece mucho mejor jaja habia optado por el lado de gestionar si estaban vacios ambos inputs, entonces que no haga las operaciones, pero queria otra manera. Esta me parece perfecta. Gracias!

Comment: Una duda, respecto a esto, cuando declaras este submit estas enviando si o si informacion a los servidores dentro de una etiqueta **form**. Hay una forma de evitar que haga eso? porque solo recarga la pagina y no muestra lo que deberia mostrar en pantalla.

Comment: @AlanStone Cuando probe esta respuesta la página no se recargaba, justamente por eso uso e.preventDefault() para evitar la recarga, después la función mostrarResultado() es intesteable porque 'operaciones' no lo tenes definido en ningun lado, debes agregar eso a tu codigo para poder probarlo

Comment: Dale ahi va, gracias! :D